# Java Is there a feature for replacing placeholders inside a String with a String variable

Tags: java, string, printf, apache-stringutils

I have a requirement to move all the hard-coded error logs to DB. Some of the error logs comes in the format

```
"xxxxx" + variable + "xxxxxx";
```

It is  not possible to change the structure of the table. Neither can I do some String insert based on the position since the values in the DB can always change.

Is there a feature in any Java libraries or third party ones where you can have placeholders in the String value and they get replaced by variables.
To quote an example, we could think of the good old

```
printf("bla %s %d bla,", var, var2);
```

or the SQL PreparedStatement class

```
stmt("select * from blah where a = ?");
```

And the '?' gets replaced by a variable content.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: `java.text.MessageFormat`, `java.util.Formatter`, take your pick.  Next time do some research before asking here, please.

Comment: In a prepared statement (at least for most drivers), the parameter placeholder is never replaced with the value. They are still sent separately to the database server.

Comment: Thank you Jim. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had done research before posting it here. Didn't use the right keywords, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK 7+ has `String.format()` which I what I think you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) like this :

```
String log = "xxxxx [{0}] xxxxxx";
String variable = "some_string";
String result = MessageFormat.format(log, variable);
```